# rails undefined method for user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

the rspec test failed this item:

```
Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
ActionView::Template::Error:
undefined method `picking?' for nil:NilClass
```

The code trigger this error is:

```
<% if current_user.picking?(post) %>
```

in the user model, picking method is defined as:
    def picking?(post)
      trips.find_by_pickedpost_id(post.id)
    end

The current_user defined as:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```

Why the test fail? why current_user is nil class?

Comment: +0. Sentences start with an upper case letter, and you haven't highlighted all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `user_from_remember_token` returns something ? I'd suggest using `debugger` or `pry` to debug your code. I find the latter easier to use, but it seems to lack features from the first.

Comment: yeah, current_user variable works well in other parts of the system

Comment: @ksol, pry can be enhanced with plugins to provide most features of debugger: banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/the-pry-ecosystem/